# New browser not packaging

Tags: application-development

I am trying to use 'quickly package' to package a new browser that I have put together as a 'trial run' in my attempt to begin learning how to use python for programming... However, even though I have followed every step TO THE LETTER (except for cosmetic stuff) when packaging I am getting this error:

```
"christopher@christopher-Inspiron-1545:~/tardisbrowser$ quickly package
.......
Command returned some WARNINGS:
----------------------------------
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  tardisbrowser/TardisbrowserWindow.py~
----------------------------------
Do you want to continue (this is not safe!)? y/[n]: y
Ubuntu packaging created in debian/
.........An error has occurred during package building
ERROR: package command failed
Aborting"
```

(I would have also posted a screenshot, however, apparently my computer is no longer saving photos EITHER! 0.0)

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is my computer just a piece of **** that needs to go out the window?

GRRRRRRR!!!!!

(Note: Running Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS)

Comment: Thanks, Pilot6. The copied text SHOULD have looked like your edit, however, AskUbuntu changed the format on me... :P

Answer (score 0):

The file it complains about is a gedit backup of `TardisbrowserWindow.py` (the ~ is used in gedit for backups). If so: delete it and try to package again.

The error about packaging is due to you using a newer version of `python-distutils-extra` than the [release supports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-distutils-extra/+bug/1021969).

This might fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra=2.38-1
```

Comment: It says that version 2.38-1 was not found... :(